# Difference in benchmark with different ARM cross compilers using hardware FP and soft VFP

Tags: compiler-construction, arm, cross-compiling

I am currently using Open virtual platform that simulates an ARM processor and I'm doing some benchmarks on a simple task started by FreeRTOS with different cross compilers.

So I encountered something strange, when I use GCC toolchain, I have to use the flag 
**-mhard-float** when compiling the software because gcc's library is compiled using hardware FP. On my benchmark I get 10 million instructions.

However, when I switched to Codesourcerys ARM eabi toolchain, I have to use the flag **-mfloat-abi=soft** to compile the software because its library is not compiled with hard floats. On this benchmark I get 30 million instructions, THREE times as slow.

The software is very simple and does not test any floats, it just start a freeRTOS task and goes through a loop printing out numbers from 0 to 10000. Simple addition of integers.

Can anyone explain the difference in hard floats and soft floats and why the benchmarks differs so much between the compilers?

Best regards
Mr Gigu

Comment: can you provide example source code to demonstrate the problem?

Comment: i tested this with several other software, and all the benchmarks seems to favor hard floats. Is it true that all software becomes faster when compiling with hard floats? I am using codesourcerys lite version which is free and it does not support a library with hard floats, for that you need to pay 1600$ :/

Comment: Is it a factor in speed difference or a a const overhead. E.g. if you let your programms print the number from 0 to 100000. Is the difference still a factor of 3, or is it just 20 million instructions more? Maybe one of the library needs some initialization code (e.g. for some sin/cos tables) which needs once a certain overhead (the 20 millions lines).

Comment: Of couse it is clear that hardware FP is faster than software emulation. So the question should not be why, but more where. Where gets actually some float function called? Maybe you should dissassemble your code and check where a function call to some fp operation is hiding (as mentioned in my other post, I would not be surprised if it is some init code).

Comment: I just removed the printfs and now the codesourcery compiler with soft floats are faster. 311k (gcc hard float) instructions and 291k (codesourcery soft float) instructions. I guess the use of printf is ALOT faster with hard floats? I'm still confused about soft floats and hard floats and why it should differ so much when I'm not even using floating points in my software.

Comment: if you provide an example program then we can explain the reason.